# Strategies for dealing with alignment issues when using the filesystem as a repository

Tags: c, io

I'm in a situation where I need to store a huge series of tuples (u32, float) in a file. The file is effectively treated as kind of array, and I'd like to be able to `mmap()` it, so that I can read values directly and edit just portions of the data, without rewriting the whole file every time a change is made.

Now, there is a problem with alignment, namely, there might padding between the two values on 64 bit archs, if the tuples are represented as a struct:

```
struct tuple {
    uint32_t x;
    float y;
};
```

For now, I have added a `#pragma pack` instruction to make sure the struct size doesn't exceed 8 bytes, assuming that it is OK (is it?) to align floats on 4-bytes boundaries, and that `sizeof(float) == 4`.

But this seems kludgy, so I thought about other ways to deal with the issue. I see two options:

- Interpret the tuple series as one long u32's array, and reinterpret the floats as such for each read/write operation.
- Abandon the possibility of mapping the file into memory directly, laboriously unpack each tuple into main memory when needed, and rewrite the whole file from time to time.

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Not kludgy at all. That is what the "pack" directive is for. I would fortify your code with a compile time assert that the structure is 8 bytes:

```
static_assert( sizeof( tuple ) == 8, "tuple not 8 bytes" );
```

Some older compilers don't support static_assert ( I think gcc pre 4.3, and pre MSVC10 )